# ExtJs 3.4 - Not able to select text in text field in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, select, extjs

I could not select the typed text in extjs text field on firefox. i can select the typed text in IE and chrome.

The problem occurs only in FF.

Any ideas or solution for this?

The problem lies in my css which allows user not able to select the text

```
.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

But i need to allow user to select the text without modifying the above css. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `selectText` method to select text

```
selectText( [Number start], [Number end] );
```

Comment: how to get the start and end values? There is no mouse event for text area. am i correct?

Comment: @AJJ you can get the field value then do value.length and set that as start and end. However, this is not working in IE for me